# Join collection query not working in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I have problem in join Collection in Magento. When i echo my query there is main_table instead of product. Here is my query and

```
SELECT `main_table`.*, `cat`.`name` FROM `product` AS `main_table` INNER JOIN `` AS `cat` ON product.cat_id = cat.id
```

Block with Action name getProductData().

```
public function getProductData()
{
         $collection = Mage::getModel('web/product')->getCollection();
         $collection->getSelect()->joinInner( array('cat'=>$this->getTable('web/web')), 'product.cat_id = cat.id', array('name'));
         //echo $collection->getSelect(); die;
         return $collection;
}
```

What i need to change in that action ? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I think you forget update config.xml and specify your table name for `$this->getTable('web/web')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's normal to consider the `product` table as `main_table` in collection but your function `$this->getTable('web/web')` is not returning the table name. You can try by using a static name of that table for testing. Or use `Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('web/web');` instead of `$this->getTable('web/web')`.

Comment: Thanks dude. But why $this->getTable('web/web') is not working ? I added my table name in config.xml

Comment: Function `getTable` is belongs resource models (Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract) but you work from block (Mage_Core_Block_Template)